# collectionview trying to call cellForItem in viewDidLoad exception

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to select some cells by traversing them and checking the text of a button. I tried checking the count of my collection view and it shows 5 before getting an exception force casting the cell.

Here's my code:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)

      let cell = ingestionCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! cvcBase

       //Set property of the cell              
}
```

When I call this exact code in the viewWillAppear I get the same exception.. when I call it in viewDidAppear I don't get an exception but I can notice a delay in the action I'm performing.

The code crashes on this line `let cell = ingestionCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! cvcBase` and if I don't force downcast then the `UICollectionViewCell` is nil.

Error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-02-20 19:43:30.093023 Project[1073:218460] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the issue because the collection view isn't loaded yet so any attempt to access cells from the collection view fail.

This is the completely wrong approach.

What you should be doing is setting up your data model as needed to indicate the desired start state of your data.

Then your implementation of the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` data source method should setup the cell appropriately based on your data model.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the property of a cell before the user sees it. What other way can I do this? And counting the items in section of my collection view a line before the exception gives back 5 items.... does this still mean it hasn't been loaded? If it has 5 items in section 0. Thanks

Comment: If you do what I state, it will happen before the user sees the cells since the cells will be displayed with the proper state. If you update your question with more specific details about what properties you mean and info about your data model, I can update my answer with more specific details.

Comment: I see what you mean... wow I don't know why I didn't just do it in the cell for item at index path.... I'm going to modify my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not unwrapping only if the cell is available:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)

      if let cell = ingestionCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? cvcBase{
       //Set property of the cell              
      }
}
```

Comment: Sure but the cell is not going to be available so my code will never get executed... the question is why isn't it available in viewDidLoad and is there any way to

Comment: The problem is this. For example, you have in your array 10 items, but the tableview can only show 3 because the cells have a large height. So you can only access 3 cells, the ones with indexpaths = 0,1,2 Thats why the app crashes, you are trying to access a cell for an indexpath that isn't visible. Rember that the tableview will only allocate the necessary tableviewcells, not all of them.